# Connection Closed error on querying BLOBs from JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, blob, jdbctemplate

I am querying a BLOB object from database and trying to write it in file system but I keep running into connection closed error. Here's the code

```
FileOutputStream out;

out = new FileOutputStream(filePathtoCreate+File.separator+filename);

        Blob inBlob= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select BLOB_CONTENT from Table_A where name = ?" , Blob.class,new Object[] { filename});
        InputStream in = inBlob.getBinaryStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I run this code I get

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getDBAccess(BLOB.java:1122)
    at oracle.sql.BLOB.getBinaryStream(BLOB.java:265)
```

I do not get this issue if I go by regular JDBC Connection, so why is this happening and how do I resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can read Blob inside [jdbcTemplate's query with RowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-), [example](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/jdbc-template-with-clob-blob.html):

> ```
> jdbcTemplate.query("select * from Report where id =?",
>               new Object[]{id}, (resultSet, i) -> {
>                   return toReport(resultSet);
>               });
>
> private Report toReport(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
>   InputStream contentStream = resultSet.getClob("CONTENT")
>                                        .getAsciiStream();
>   String content =
>           new Scanner(contentStream, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
>   report.setContent(content);
>   Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("IMAGE");
> ```
>
> Query given SQL to create a prepared statement from SQL and a list of arguments to bind to the query, mapping each row to a result object via a RowMapper.